# Running TBB code on windows 7 using code blocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, tbb

i have installed TBB setup for windows 7 and want to execute code in it.i don't have visual studio setup and i have code blocks IDE. i want to execute my TBB code in it.Pls Help to configure Code Blocks.
I have done Linker settings i.e i have included libraries from this path

C:\Program Files\Intel\Composer XE 2013\tbb\lib\ia32\

and i have set search directory to

C:\Program Files\Intel\Composer XE 2013\tbb\include\tbb

still also when i compile it gives error tbb/task_scheduler_init.h :No such file or directory.

Can anyone pls suggest how to run TBB code in windows??

Comment: Does the `C:\Program Files\Intel\Composer XE 2013\tbb\include\tbb\task_scheduler_init.h` file even exist?

Comment: @shakurov Yes they are present in this path C:\Program Files\Intel\Composer XE 2013\tbb\include\tbb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have set the search directory to
>
> C:\Program Files\Intel\Composer XE 2013\tbb\include\tbb

Pretty clear from the error message and the location of the file you gave that you should have set the search directory to

C:\Program Files\Intel\Composer XE 2013\tbb\include

Comment: Thanks @john for reply it worked ,nw it gives error undefined reference to tbb::task_scheduler_init::initialize(int,unsigned int) ....for the line in code as "task_scheduler_init init1"

Comment: How you told code blocks which libraries to link with? I know you've said the library directory, but you probably also need to give the names of the TBB libraries.

Comment: All the libraries that were is this path "C:\Program Files\Intel\Composer XE 2013\tbb\lib\ia32\vc_mt" i have included that . for e.g tbb.lin,tbb_debug.lin and all

Comment: OK, well I know nothing about code blocks or TBB I'm afraid. But almost certainly you haven't told code blocks to link in the right way.